# Upload assets to Nginx as CDN when create a war [GRAILS]

Tags: grails, nginx, groovy, cdn

I want implement a CDN for statics from my web-app (css/js/img) and I use Nginx server as CDN, but I dont known how to upload assets to the server when I start create the ".war"

I use groovy/grails and the "cdn-assets-pipeline" plugin dont work becasue it is only for S3 or CloudFront amazon providers, and i want use nginx server.

I think that use the event "eventCreateWarStart" on _Events.groovy may be a good idea, but how upload files to nginx server?

```
eventCreateWarStart = { name, stageDir ->
    grailsConsole.log('starting war!') 
}
```

Can you help me?

Thanks and sorry for my english!

Comment: Never apologize for speaking a 2nd language, no matter how well or poorly you think you are able to speak it. Maybe you could look at the source code for the cdn-assets-pipeline to find out how they do it for S3 and use that to implement for your own?

Comment: Thanks @Gregg, I'll try do it